# unable to create usb stick for windows 7 from ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, live-usb, unetbootin, usb-creator

I followed the same process which mentioned in below link to create USB stick for windows:

[How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu)

But WinUSB throws following error while syncing:

[image]

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try dd command.

The dd command copies a file, converting the format of the data in the process, according to the operands specified.

Operands:

if=FILE -- Read from file instead of stdin.

of=FILE -- Write to file instead of stdout

bs=BYTES -- Read and write bytes at a time.

count=BLOCKS -- Copy only input blocks.

sync -- Use synchronized I/O for metadata.

Example:

Open a terminal.

Run it:

```
sudo -i

fdisk -l  (Identify your usb-stick, suppose is /dev/sdb)

dd if=/path-to-your-iso/Win_7_64Bit.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=4M; sync
```

Note: Always clearly identify the usb-stick with fdisk -l command, improperly entering the wrong values could inadvertently overwrite the data on the hard drive.