# how to create windows bootable usb stick from ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, live-usb

I refered many links like 
[How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu)
and [unable to create usb stick for windows 7 from ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524981/unable-to-create-usb-stick-for-windows-7-from-ubuntu-14-04).I installed **WinUsb** and **Unetbooin** packages.Also I tried with **dd**.But I can not create windows bootable usb from ubuntu.how can i create **Windows bootable stick** from **ubuntu**.

Comment: I've tried to make an USB bootable Win10 from the official original ISO this weekend using **dd** (`sudo dd if=/path.to.iso.iso of=/dev/sdc1 bs=4M && sync`) - no success :/ I've tried the very same ISO then using **rufus** in other computer with Windows and it worked. Any ideas?

Comment: @crysman i created windows usb stick using poweriso.exe from windows environment.

Comment: I tried many ubuntu packages but it was not done in ubuntu environment.

Comment: Use wine and try with poweriso.exe in ubuntu